# Javascript: If something gets visible blend it in

Tags: javascript, function, aframe, visible, blending

i want something really specific. I develop an vr-experience with a-frame.
I have many events which sets the visibility of an object to "false":

```
document.getElementById('button').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
```

Now my Question: It dosn´t look well when they suddenly pop up but when i try to blend them in i need an animation for all objects which gets visible. Can i make an script which says when something gets visible it should blend in instead of poping up?

Comment: css transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple example using css transitions, note that you could perform several transitions on the same element. Full example Here https://jsfiddle.net/9hvede11/ 
We have two (could be more) classes. In this case in the beginning the element have a `.short` class, then because of some event, it changes to `.large`. The transition property is saying how to accomplish the transition from the previous state.

```
.short{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.large{
   transition: width .2s, height 2s, background-color 2s;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   width: 200px;
}
```

in pure Javascript you have something like:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){ //some event  
var div = document.getElementById("square");
div.className="large"; //change class 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With A-frame, you'll want to create an animation element as a child of the 'button' entity, then set the begin attribute to be a named event:

```
<a-entity id="button" material="opacity: 1">
    <a-animation attribute="material.opacity"
           dur="1000"
           to="0"
           begin="myEvent"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

...

```
document.getElementById('button').emit('myEvent');
```

Relevant documentation:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#emitting-an-event-with-emit

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/animations.html